# php exec() function Take too long time and no result in the end

Tags: php, centos

I tried to run python script in my webserver using php script but, when I open the browser and run the php file, it's always loading but no result in the end. but if I run my php file in shell it's working properly.

this is my php code :

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(310);
$a="text";
$b="21-11-17";
$c="22-11-17";
$d="1";
$tmp = exec("/usr/bin/python /path/to/my/python/file.py $a $b $c $d");
echo $tmp;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to add the second parameter to `exec()` and then see what populates it to know what's happening when you run this. Also, make sure that this script can be run by your webserver user (permissions-wise).

Comment: How fast does it execute directly?